# Make "Advance slide" go to an arbitrary slide?

Tags: keynote

I have a Keynote with 10 slides. How can I make it so that when the user advances on from slide 5, it goes back to slide 3?

Essentially the order of clicking through slides should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, ...

---

I was able to hack something together by putting a transparent rectangle on top of the entire slide 5 and adding a link back to slide 3. However, this has several problems:

- It's hacky to set up.
- It's hard to edit the slide when there is a transparent shape on top of everything.
- I suspect that if I'm using a clicker instead of a mouse, it won't invoke this link.
- etc.

What I really want is to just tell it which slide it should advance to after this one. Is there a way to do that in Keynote?